# Web scrape with VBA but getElementsByTagName("div") not work with MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

My VBA's **GOAL** is to print "**2025-08-04**" of **Warranty Expiration** from URL web page.

https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/kr/en/products/servers/thinksystem/sr650/7x06/7x06cto1ww/j30a7xlg/warranty

Part of html is below containing my goal.

```html
<strong data-v-6ab7fc02="">2025-08-04</strong>
```

I'd appreciate code (if possible) or advice for the GOAL because I tried many real trials without success.

With my 1-trial code, `getElementsByTagName("div")` skips class names between

class name of `"content-placeholder-line content-placeholder-line--block"` and `"kindly-reminder mobileview"`.

With my 2-trial, `oTr.Children` doesn't print 2 of # of classes (`left-area special-tag` and `right-area`) what I expect.

```vb
'my VBA Code below
Sub get_warrantyDate_B()

    Dim oreq  As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set oreq = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim url As String
    Dim ohtml As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
      
    Dim oTrs  As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim oTr As IHTMLElement

    Dim oTrs2  As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim oTr2 As IHTMLElement
      
    url = "https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/kr/en/products/servers/thinksystem/sr650/7x06/7x06cto1ww/j30a7xlg/warranty"
    oreq.Open "GET", url
    oreq.send
        
    '---------------------------------------------------------
    If oreq.Status <> 200 Then '' READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        Debug.Print oreq.Status & " - " & oreq.statusText: Exit Sub
    Else
        Debug.Print "Success to " & url
    End If
    '---------------------------------------------------------
    ohtml.Body.innerHTML = oreq.responseText
        
    'my 1-trial
    Set oTrs = ohtml.getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each oTr In oTrs
        Debug.Print "(" & oTr.ClassName & ")"
    Next

    'my 2-trial
    Set oTrs = ohtml.getElementsByTagName("section")
        
    For Each oTr In oTrs       
        If oTr.ClassName = "main-frame" Then
            
            Debug.Print oTr.tagName & "   " & oTr.ClassName & " " & oTr.Children.Length
            For Each oTr2 In oTr.Children
                Debug.Print "class=(" & oTr2.tagName & ")"
            Next
        End If            
    Next oTr
              
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that if you load the website using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` you get the HTML code of that site but no JavaScript is processed. So anything that will be loaded through AJAX/JavaScript techniques is not in that code. This is the case with this website and the reason why you cannot find the desired data. What you need to do is to use a webbrowser that actually runs the scripts and then access the HTML in that browser. Do some research on Chrome Selenium.

Comment: hi PEH. I also think it's better to try on Selenium. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi all PEH, Based on PEH advice. I share my result.   Debug.Print chd.FindElementByCss("#app-psp-warranty > div.psp-warranty__body > div > div.psp-warranty__status > div > div.warranty-status__content > div > div.chart-time-bucket > div.chart-expires > p.chart-info").Text
    Debug.Print chd.FindElementByCss("#app-psp-warranty > div.psp-warranty__body > div > div.psp-warranty__status > div > div.warranty-status__content > div > div.chart-time-bucket > div.chart-expires > p:nth-child(2) > strong").Text

Comment: Hi all, I posted new Q which relates with this post.
If have time, Please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561753/web-scrape-click-button-with-chrome-selenium-on-short-vba-code