# Web Scrape click button with Chrome Selenium on short VBA code

Tags: html, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My Goal is to click Submit Button(Here in Korea) of URL below.
"https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/us/ko/warrantylookup#/".
The VBA source code puts "j30a7xlg" using Sendkeys sucessfully.

After that, to click button, I tried with css selector without success. The error image is attached.

I also tried with xPath below. but failed.

```vb
chd.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='app-standalone-warrantylookup']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button and text()='제출']").Click
```

So Please advise or code for how to click the button.
If need more info,let me know.

```vb
Private BR_wty As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Sub ChromeExe(ByVal c As ChromeDriver, ByVal URL As String)
c.Get URL
End Sub

Sub Scrape_WTYMY1() 'warranty   
Dim URL As String, i As Integer
URL = "https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/us/ko/warrantylookup#/"
Call ChromeExe(BR_wty, URL)
    
Dim chd As New Selenium.ChromeDriver    '//Local var
Set chd = BR_wty
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
chd.FindElementByClass("button-placeholder__input").SendKeys "j30a7xlg"
    
'Q1: how to click button ERROR (image for Run-time error 11)
chd.FindElementByCss("#app-standalone-warrantylookup > div > div.warranty-lookup__content > div > div > div.basic-search__content > button").Click

Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]
Any VBA code(draft) or advice will be helpful for my goal.

Comment: We need much better information from you: "Error" is no error description. We need a) What was intended, what was your goal? b) What went wrong, what did it do instead? c) If there is an error where is it and what is the error message? d) "how to get new URL for next operation" How would we know what your next operation is if you don't tell us? Please [edit] your question and add a lot more details.

Comment: first capture the element with the Find method as `set myButton = chd.find....` then try the method `myButton.scrollIntoView` on the element before you do the click.

Comment: Not solved. I tried igittr method. But I have another run-time error at the line of "myButton = chd.FindElementByCss". Dim myButton As Selenium.WebElement 'Run-time error '91': 'Object variable or With block variable not set myButton = chd.FindElementByCss("#app-standalone-warrantylookup > div > div.warranty-lookup__content > div > div > div.basic-search__content > button")